# Spying Adobe Acrobat within Blue Prism keeps giving the error "There was an error during the spying operation."

Tags: automation, acrobat, blueprism, rpa

I am trying to spy Adobe Acrobat within Blue Prism so that I can convert an open PDF to word in order to copy all data to clipboard. Adobe acrobat launches fine however when spying the elements using AA mode (I have tried all 3) I get this error:

"There was an error during the spying operation."
"System.ApplicationException: The window spied was not found in the model
   at BluePrism.AMI.clsAMI.Spy(clsElementTypeInfo& elementType, List`1& identifiers)
   at AutomateUI.frmIntegrationAssistant.HandleSpyOrLaunchClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)"

Now from my knowledge this error appears when there is a second instance open as BP tries to connect to the background process however in this case I have ensured that there is no other instance of acrobat open that could cause this.

How would I go about spying elements of Acrobat without encountering this error so that I can use global mouse clicks to utilize the spied elements and convert my PDF ?

Comment: Automating Acrobat in that way is a violation of the EULA. If you want to automate extracting text from a PDF, use one of the many PDF library tools. Some are even free.

Comment: You may want to look into automating [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/), or just using the MS Word VBO to open the PDF directly to Word, which has worked for me in certain circumstances before.

Comment: Can't you use BP to open the PDF from within Microsoft Word? Word provides a conversion option for PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

Disable Protected Mode (Sandbox Protections) in Preferences / Security (Enhanced).

It is a sandbox which causes BP to see two processes instead of just one.

Answer (score -1):

in the pdf document go to edit-> Preferences-> security(enhanced)-> uncheck the option enable protected mode at start up as shown below. It worked for me.